# The error estimates of the implicit Euler method in the book have different results

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I use **DSolve** and **NDSolve** to solve a set of differential equations respectively, where **NDSolve** specifies an *implicit Euler* method, and subtract the results of both solutions to obtain the truncation error curve, maximum truncation error, and corresponding positions of the implicit Euler method.

The code is as follows：

```
tstart = 0;
tend = 0.08;
stepsize = 0.00006;
n = (tend - tstart)/stepsize;
(*DSolve*)
sol1 = DSolve[{l il'[t] == vl[t], c vc'[t] == ic[t], 
    ir[t] == -ic[t] + il[t], vl[t] == 24 - vc[t], vr[t] == vc[t], 
    vr[t] == r ir[t], il[0] == 0, vc[0] == 0}, {ir[t], il[t], ic[t], 
    vr[t], vl[t], vc[t]}, t];
il[t_] = il[t] /. sol1[[1]];
pars1 = {r -> 22, l -> 2 10^-1, c -> 1 10^-4};
a = Evaluate[il[t] /. pars1];
Dil = Table[a, {t, 0, 0.08, stepsize}, 1];
(*NDSolve*)
components1 = {vI == ll iL'[t] + vC[t], 
   vC'[t] == iL[t]/cc - vC[t]/(rr cc), vC[0] == 0, iL[0] == 0};
pars2 = {vI -> 24, rr -> 22, ll -> 2 10^-1, cc -> 1 10^-4};
sol2 = NDSolve[{components1} /. pars2, {iL}, {t, 0, .2}, 
   StartingStepSize -> stepsize, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> {"LinearlyImplicitEuler"}}];
a = Evaluate[iL[t] /. sol2[[1]]];
NDil = Table[a, {t, 0, 0.08, stepsize}, 1];
(*Calculation error*)
errort = Table[tstart + stepsize*i, {i, 0, n}];
ilerror = Table[0, {i, 0, n}];
For[k = 1, k < n + 1, k++,
  ilerror[[k]] = Dil[[k, 1]] - NDil[[k, 1]];
  ];
p1 = Table[Transpose[{errort, ilerror}], 1];
ListLinePlot[p1, AxesLabel -> {"s", "il[t]/A"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"LinearlyImplicitEuler"}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
ilpeak = FindPeaks[Abs[ilerror]]
{{151, 0.00191949}}
```

From the operation results, we can see that the maximum truncation error of *il* at the 151st point is 0.001919.

The following image is an error estimate for the implicit Euler method seen in a book.
[image]

The calculation code for this method is as follows：

```
{r = 22, l = 2 10^-1, c = 1 10^-4, vi = 24, stepsize = 0.00006};
\[CapitalDelta]vi = 0;
A = {{0, -1/l}, {1/c, -1/(r c)}};
G = Inverse[A];
B = {1/l, 0};
Subscript[X, n + 1] = 
  Transpose[{{0.7909637667818027, 14.280468663134522}}];(*The il value of the 152nd position is calculated by DSolve*)
Error = Transpose[{{ilerror, vcerror}}];
Error = (-1/2*stepsize*stepsize*A . A) . (Subscript[X, n + 1] + 
    G . (B*(vi + \[CapitalDelta]vi) + 
       G . B*\[CapitalDelta]vi/stepsize))
{{0.000012766639933902838`}, {0.00028584581003691066`}}
```

The 0.000012766639933902838 in the calculation result is the *il* error calculated using the error estimation formula in the literature(ss shown in the picture).

The comparison shows that the results calculated by the two methods (*0.001919...* and *0.0000127...*) differ greatly. What is the reason for this? Is it related to Mathematica's built-in algorithm?

Comment: Try `implicitEuler = {"FixedStep", 
  Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", 
    "Coefficients" -> "ImplicitRungeKuttaRadauIIACoefficients", 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 1}}` instead of `"LinearlyImplicitEuler"`, which is a different method.

Comment: To learn more about linearly implicit Euler method, see e.g. https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/3247/5331

Comment: @MichaelE2 Hi, MichaelE2! I tried the method you gave for NDSolve calculation, and the final result is very close to the original...

Comment: Then please show us your modified code.

Comment: 1. Which book are you refering to? 2. What's the definition of $\mathit{\mathbf{A}}$, $\mathbf{B}$, $\mathbf{u}_n$, etc.? 3. Are you sure you've implemented the formula correctly? I bet your understanding for $\mathbf{u}_n$ is wrong, it's probably a vector just like $\mathbf{x}_n$ from the context.

Comment: @xzczd I also asked in the community. This book is attached[link](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2852119?p_p_auth=C9YanMoO)

Comment: Then it's clear your implementation is wrong. The $\mathbf{u}_n$ should be a vector.